# Segoe UI Emoji font - black and white in Chrome, colored in Firefox

Tags: ubuntu, google-chrome, firefox, fonts

I'm using Ubuntu 17.04 and I installed the `Segoe UI Emoji` font because most emojis were missing. Now I see all emojis on http://getemoji.com/.

While the emojis are colored in Firefox 54.0, they are black and white in Chrome 59.0.3071.115.

I checked `Rendered Fonts` in Chrome and it says `Segoe UI Emoji — Local file (597 glyphs)`. In Firefox under `Fonts` it says `Segoe UI Emoji` `system` `Used as: "Segoe UI Emoji"`. So it seems like both browsers are using the same font, but only Firefox displays colors.

How can I fix it in Chrome without changing Ubuntu's oder Chrome's default font?

Answer (score 1):

They may indeed be using the same font, but color fonts usually have monochrome fallback versions of each glyph for programs that don't support them, or where they're disabled. In this case, it's probably going to be a matter of configuring Chrome or Ubuntu itself. [This article](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2016/08/enable-color-emoji-linux-google-chrome-noto) might help.

Comment: I read that article before. "You may find some GTK desktop applications have issues displaying regular text correctly after following this tutorial." Commenters mentioned that it breaks applications that I'm using, so I haven't considered that solution.